# Run Asp.net 5 vNext project (MVC6) publish build on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core

I configurated everything according to some resources on the internet, but i don't know what i miss..

When i try to start it manually (Which works on my local computer!) i get the following result on the server:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\approot\myproject\approot
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\approot\myproject\approot> .\web
Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web, kestrel.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadFile(String assemblyPath)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContex
t)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.LoaderContainer.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.DefaultLoadContext.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoaderCache.GetOrAdd(AssemblyName name, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadAssemblyImpl(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.ResolveAssembly(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

Things done on Windows Server 2012:

1. Installed DNVM/DNX
2. Enabled features IIS & Application server (Selected Web server (IIS) Support for the application server as well)
3. .Net 4.5.2 is installed.

DNVM list outputs:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win             default
```

Which is the same as used in my project and local computer.

I also looked for the stdout.log from IIS as i also tried setting it up with iis. but no luck. And no log is created or can be found.

For the record the project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },


  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

If additional information is required please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why yet, as i assume that a publish will contain everything to be able to run. But.. i found an resolution.

If you go to the Approot > SRC > ProjectName folder in powershell on the server and run dnu restore.. the web.cmd will suddenly work! As it loads the missing packages!